Preserving All Frames
I want to extract all frames from my videos (because again, manually selecting the ones I want would take too much time) so I can select the best ones to capture its art style and the characters from them for my AI art and also to upload to DeviantArt. Problem is, when I use ffmpeg and Shutter Encoder to make the PNG files, it took a ton of space on my computer (like 100GB).
Here are the things I tried:

Exporting the frames as JPGs but they weren't nearly indistinguishable from the videos.
Export them as EXR and TIFF files, but they resulted in higher file sizes than PNG.
Change the scale of the images of the videos to from 1080p to 360p so I can resize them later, but as you guys said, I'll just lose quality.

There, I describe my problem, and my process. Now what solutions can you give me for this?

I have a 1080p video, so how do I lower the resolution, and bring it back up again without losing quality?

You keep asking this same question; highly respected people keep giving you the same answer. Please save yourself some trouble and LISTEN to them.  You can't lower the resolution of images and then put back what you've taken out. That'd be rather like trying to make stew, then later reconstructing the original meat & veg that went into the stew. SUGGESTION:  save the images as JPG. Experiment with different compression levels. You can probably find one that doesn't visibly affect the images but will be MUCH smaller than the equivalent PNG

If you want a video for a website, use a MP4 video.

YEah this is a valid question. your best bet is just to split the file. There is unfortunately no good answer to the question

If storage space is an issue when working, that's a hardware/financial issue. The solution is to acquire hardware that does not limit the ability to work - in other words, get a bigger drive or an external drive. Trying to limit the work to fit on inadequate hardware is just the wrong way to go.

No, you cannot down save a file and then get back the original resolution. There is always going to be a trade-off between quality and space. Lossless quality inherently requires more storage space than lossy compression. For web purposes, a slight loss in quality might be acceptable if it results in significantly smaller file sizes.
You can either change the compression type, frame/image size, or the amount of frames that you're extracting per second.

How do I change frame/image size without losing quality?

@CalvinJack - you can't. It's not possible

I don't think you understand how image resolution works. Once you lower an image file resolution, you're deleting details from it - these details don't exist anywhere anymore, so you can't bring it back.
When you get a 1080p video and lower the resolution to 720p you threw away A LOT of detail. You can resample it up to 1080p but you're simply making pixels larger (hence blurry image result), you're not adding detail back to it.
Modern AI upscalers can add more detail to images, by guessing what it should look like: it doesn't know what the original looked like so it fakes it based on similar images it's trained on. You will get a more detailed image, but it will not look like the original.
